# Handling all possible results in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a clause `is_adjacent([X1,Y1], [X2,Y2])` which is true, when `[X2,Y2]` is a neighbor of `[X1,Y1]`. I get all possible results (four) if i ask `is_adjacent([2,2], [X,Y])`, in this case:

```
is_adjacent([2,2],[X,Y]).
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 2 ;
X = 2,
Y = 1 ;
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

I want to use this behavior in another clause:

```
anotherClause :-
    is_adjacent([2,2],[X,Y]),
    [to be continued...].
```

Now, how can i work automatically with every possible result? For example if i want to check if every single result is a member of a specific list.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: so you need to check if two lists have the same members, irregardless of order?

Answer (score 1):

there is [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2, that seems to fit your requirements:

```
% this fails because not all results are in list
anotherClause :-
    forall(is_adjacent([2, 2], [X, Y]),
           memberchk([X, Y], [[2, 3], [3, 2]])).

% this succeed, all results are in list
anotherClause :-
    forall(is_adjacent([2, 2], [X, Y]),
           memberchk([X, Y], [[2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]])).
```

for test purpose, I coded is_adjacent this way:

```
is_adjacent([A, B], [X, Y]) :-
    member(U / V, [1 / 0, 0 / 1, -1 / 0, 0 / -1]),
    X is A + U, Y is B + V.
```

Answer (score 0):

To check every result of `is_adjacent` against some other rule, all you need to do is to write that rule in terms of `X` and `Y`, like this:

```
anotherClause :-
    is_adjacent([2,2],[X,Y]),
    X > 0,
    Y > 0,
    check_x_and_y(X, Y, Result),
    ...
```

and so on. When you evaluate `anotherClause`, Prolog will unify `X` and `Y` with the first set of values, and then go on with the rest of the clause (above, it's checking that `X` and `Y` are greater than zero, and evaluating the two variables with the `check_x_and_y` rule. Once the rule comes up with a set of assignments, it gives them to you, and lets you stop or continue. If you want to always continue until the whole set is exhausted (e.g. to print all assignments of `X` and `Y`), the pattern looks like this:

```
anotherClause :-
    is_adjacent([2,2],[X,Y]),
    print_x_and_y(X,Y),
    fail.

anotherClause.
```

The first rule goes through each assignment of `X`, `Y`, prints them, and then fail to trigger re-evaluation. The second rule is a catch-all fact to stop further evaluation.

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/j73a5K) that prints all pairs of adjacent cells.

Comment: That's imperative way to handle results. While its ok to print, that can't be used for "check if every single result is a member of a specific list". Maybe I'm wrong but "every single result" can be written with quantifier ∀ (for all)

Comment: @ony The OP is writing a maze walker (see his other question), so he *wants* an imperative approach. He even says so himself: "how can i work automatically with every possible result?" It's his "for example..." that mislead you. This is a good answer, you shouldn't have downvoted it.

Comment: the fact that person isn't yet so deep in the declarative languages doesn't justify answers that leads away from the idea having high-level language for representing facts and inference rules. If person will go the way this answer leads he'll end up with using `assert`/`retract`/etc for "global variables" to say that some of alternatives doesn't contained in the specific list.

Comment: @ony Prolog is a general purpose language, not a language only for "representing facts and inference rules" (although it can do that, too). Nowhere do you find me talking about asserts and retracts either: it's a slippery slope fallacy on your end.

Comment: The only thing you can do with approach in this answer is to modify global state (i.e. IO and other stuff). While high order `farall/2`, `setof/3` and others allows you to do anything including IO in a more natural way, I think.

Comment: @ony This does not mean that my approach is somehow invalid, or does not do what the OP wants to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28512/discussion-between-ony-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect all solutions, I think you might be looking for the set of predicate `setof`. This finds all solutions of a predicate.

`setof([X,Y], is_ajacent([2,2],[X,Y], Z)`

then

`Z = [[2,3], [1,2], ...]`

If you don't want to collect all solutions, but simply do something for each solution, then do as dasblinkenlight second solution shows. specifically `fail` at the end so Prolog tries the next solution. Then finally succeed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to transform ∀ (for all) into ∃ (there exists) with double-not approach:
∀x.f(x) = ¬¬∀x.f(x) = ¬∃x.¬f(x)

```
anotherClause :- \+(notAnotherClause).
notAnotherClause :- is_adjacent([2,2],[X,Y]), \+(memberchk([X,Y], SomeList)).
```

Idea is that we search for existence of negative result within all alternatives and absence of that actually means "for all variants".

P.S. `\+/1` (`\+(Goal)`) sometimes written as `not/1` (`not(Goal)`)